# Radio selected value generated by php

Tags: php, html, html-select

I am making html page with php script. For some elements I show which type it is and I select type of this element, but when I create html page that type is selected in code but it isn't selected on dropdown that you can see. The varialbe $assesing_method tells what is the type of some elements. My code is bellow:

So if the type is: RADIO I allways get some generated HTML code like this:

```
 <option value='text' selected='selected' >TEXT FIELD</option>
 <option value='textarea'>textarea</option>
 <option value='radio'>radiobutton</option>
```

My php code:

```
 $generatedHtml.="<select id='typeQuestion' name='typeQuestion'>";
if(strcmp($assesing_method,"text")==0){
        $generatedHtml.="<option value='text' selected='selected' >TEXT FIELD</option>";
}
else{
     $generatedHtml.="<option value='text'>Text field</option>";
}
if(strcmp($assesing_method,"textarea")==0){
   $generatedHtml.="<option selected='selected' value='textarea'>TEXTAREA</option>";
    }
else{
   $generatedHtml.="<option value='textarea'>textarea</option>";
}
if(strcmp($assesing_method,"radio")==0){
     $generatedHtml.="<option selected='selected' value='radio'>RADIO BUTTONS</option>";
}
else{
$generatedHtml.="<option value='radio'>radiobutton</option>";
}
$generatedHtml.="</select>";
```

Comment: what is $assesing_method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use strong string comparison

so you should compare as following

```
$generatedHtml.="<select id='typeQuestion' name='typeQuestion'>";
if(strtolower($assesing_method) == 'text'){
        $generatedHtml.="<option value='text' selected='selected' >TEXT FIELD</option>";
}
else{
     $generatedHtml.="<option value='text'>Text field</option>";
}
if(strtolower($assesing_method) == 'textarea'){
   $generatedHtml.="<option selected='selected' value='textarea'>TEXTAREA</option>";
    }
else{
   $generatedHtml.="<option value='textarea'>textarea</option>";
}
if(strtolower($assesing_method) == 'radio'){
     $generatedHtml.="<option selected='selected' value='radio'>RADIO BUTTONS</option>";
}
else{
$generatedHtml.="<option value='radio'>radiobutton</option>";
}
$generatedHtml.="</select>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that string comparison with strcmp is case sensitive, so "RADIO" != "radio".